# Python: Importing from your project without setting PYTHONPATH manually

Tags: python

How can I import packages and modules from different places in my project without resetting the PYTHONPATH (because that seems like a 'hacky' solution).

For example if I have the following directory structure:

```
proj
├── __init__.py
├── important_file.py
└── subdirectory/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── script.py
```

How can I import important_file.py from inside script.py?  Can I somehow specify in my project that `proj` is my root directory, so that I can import important file with `import proj.important_file`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/root/directory')
```

to import from whatever directory you like. At least, this worked for me in the past. Maybe there are even less "hacky" solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative imports

```
# inside subdirectory/script.py
from .. import important_file
```

but really the best solution is to add it to your `PYTHONPATH` and do

```
import proj.important_file
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `PYTHONPATH` for relative imports within packages though?  Just `from .. import module` is all that's needed as far as the OP's question is worded.

Comment: @Iguananaut you shouldn't be doing relative imports at all. Of course it doesn't make sense to do BOTH. I've edited to clarify

Comment: I disagree--relative imports are fine if it's part of the project's policy. Just because Guido doesn't like them doesn't make them wrong, or they wouldn't be part of the language.

Comment: @Iguananaut I feel like it's more that removing them is a huge backwards incompatible change. They decidedly make your project more brittle and easier to break. Absolute imports are *absolutely* (a hyuk) better.

Comment: We use them because we find it makes the project less brittle and easier to adapt to API changes.  But this isn't the place for a flame war.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer "pythonic" solutions, not necessarily what @Gijs suggested which I would call more of a work around.

So this is something I haven't done much of but when I've needed to do it, I've spent a lot of time on it. Take a look at this [my repo](https://github.com/austinlostinboston/first-repo/). In it, I have a unit testing directory, which I import core.py into test_core.py.

The project folder is structured as follows.

```
SNA (this is called first-repo on git, but SNA on my machine)
├── bin/
└── sna/
    ├── core.py
    └── test/
        └── test_core.py
```

In `text_core.py`, I import my functions from core.py. I do this by using the following line.

```
from SNA.sna.core import *
```

So a general format is this.

```
from PROJECTNAME.DIR.FILE import * (or specific functions)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This requires that `SNA` is in `PYTHONPATH`, which is explicitly what OP is trying to avoid for some reason

Comment: I did this about a year ago but I don't remember changing anything with my python path.

Comment: Then you must have put the directory somewhere on your `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` originally. Python doesn't know how to import a module that's not found on the path.